# resnet50 - increasing training speed? keras

Tags: keras, classification, resnet

hth do I increase the speed of this? I mean the loss is moving down by hairs. HAIRS.

```
Epoch 1/30
4998/4998 [==============================] - 307s 62ms/step - loss: 0.6861 - acc: 0.6347
Epoch 2/30
4998/4998 [==============================] - 316s 63ms/step - loss: 0.6751 - acc: 0.6387
Epoch 3/30
4998/4998 [==============================] - 357s 71ms/step - loss: 0.6676 - acc: 0.6387
Epoch 4/30
4998/4998 [==============================] - 376s 75ms/step - loss: 0.6625 - acc: 0.6387
Epoch 5/30
4998/4998 [==============================] - 354s 71ms/step - loss: 0.6592 - acc: 0.6387
Epoch 6/30
4998/4998 [==============================] - 345s 69ms/step - loss: 0.6571 - acc: 0.6387
Epoch 7/30
4998/4998 [==============================] - 349s 70ms/step - loss: 0.6559 - acc: 0.6387
```

Model Architecture: 
[resnet50 (CNN with skip connections)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSQtv.png)

Except instead of 1 FC I have two. And I changed the softmax output to sigmoid for binary classification.

num positive training data: 1806 
num neg training data:  3192

My output is represented by a 1 or 0 for each example ( [0, 0, 1, 1, ...])

batches = 40, num epochs =30, but that doesn't matter because the loss stopped

Comment: It is very hard to say any thing without considering the model architecture. Can you post the code for your model architecture?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem.

Comment: thanks for your contribution Mat

Comment: @Mitiku architecture posted

Comment: since when does machine learning have nothing to do with programming? @MatiasValdenegro #thingsAGeniusWouldSay